# Can I run two different graphics card on my motherboard

Tags: windows, windows-10

So I’m currently in the process of building a computer! I’m trying to build a workstation/gaming computer. I do some pretty heavy solidworks files up to 50 parts+ Including a lot of rendering and shadowing so for my price range the NVIDIA Quadro p2000 is the graphics card for me! But 50 percent of time I also game! So I was wondering if I could combine for example the NVIDIA Quadro p2000 with a G-force GTX 1060 in one mother board? I know If this is possible i would probably have to run two different monitors for the two different video cards each having the one HDMI cable and have a pretty beefy power supply! I’m a noob as you tell at this but bringing my knowledge up as for everyone building there computers for the first time! Anyways thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, running two different graphics cards is supported on most motherboards and graphics cards. However, given the graphics cards you mentioned for your workload, I think spending just a bit more on a GTX 1080 or 1080ti would greatly simplify things for you. The GTX 1080 has more rendering and gaming power than a P2000 and would cost about the same as a P2000 plus a 1060.

Let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: Alright thank you so much for the advice I really appreciate it Cancun101

Comment: @Skyw No problem! Since I see you're a new user, it helps if you accept an answer that solved your problem by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Alright thank you man! Since you recommended a graphics card for me! What mother board do you think I should use I’m looking at the ASUS ROG STRIX B250H right now!

Comment: That motherboard is actually last-generation, meaning it will not have full functionality with the latest generation of intel processors. A similar motherboard from this generation would be the ASUS ROG STRIX B360-F GAMING. The next thing to think about is a processor - that really depends on how much power you'll need.

Comment: By the way, pcpartpicker.com is your friend here - it does a really great job of pointing out incompatibility issues between components.

Comment: Okay great thank you il be using intel i7 8700k so I was incorrect in my choice! Again thank you and I will take a look at that!